# PHP time calculation with different days and timezones

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm working on a PHP solution for a radio station at the moment that requires me to determine whether the current time ("H:I" format) is between a set time frame.

The schedule comprises of intervals of 2 hours (starting at either 12midnight or 1am). This schedule is changeable dependent on a user selected timezone (or default setting).

The issue I'm having is determining whether the current time is between any of these times. For example, whether 2am is between 00:00 and 02:00, 04:00 etc.

Ultimately, I want to highlight the timeframe in which the current time falls.

I apologise if I'm being unclear in anything I've put, and I can explain further if necessary.

Comment: Can we see a snippet of what you're using to calculate? Depending on how your doing your time calcs, you could always convert it to a unix timestamp using [mktime](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) then finding a range may be simpler.

Comment: Please be more specific.  Is the schedule for a particular date? Or is it a recurring schedule?  How are you getting the time zone from the user? Are they selecting an actual time zone like "America/New_York", or are they just selecting an offset like UTC-05:00 ?  Are you asking about time zone adjustments? Or range queries? Or both?  The only thing I can advise based on the current wording is that you should use half-open intervals like `[00:00, 2:00)` when working with time.  2:00 is not in that interval, it belongs to the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DateTime and DateInterval classes: http://hu1.php.net/datetime . I don't think different day and timezone is an issue in them...

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't make myself very clear. I need to adjudge whether the date falls on the next day (or partially) for example, 10pm-12am, 11pm-1am. My calculations are fine when determining 8pm - 10pm for example.

Comment: @HeartOfScotland - if you test the date of your start time in the time zone of the user, and the date of the end time, then you can see whether it spans midnight. If the date is the same, it doesn't. Combine that with the classes above and you should have your answer.

Comment: Thank you all - I do apologise for being so unspecific. I utilised the DateTime class as detailed on the PHP.net website.

By comparing the user specified timezone to Europe/London and then reformatting the output as H:i, I was able to compare the times appropriately.

Comment: @HeartOfScotland : You weren't unspecific, but I'd rather help you to find the proper way instead of solving your problem with a complete code...